# wamp server php extension PECL Missing

Tags: php, wampserver, pecl

Does any one know why the PECL extension in wamp server does not exists?

I am trying to use the `http_build_url()`
but I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function http_build_url() in ...

Comment: Well, is the `pecl_http` extension installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `http_build_url()` is part of the PECL extension `pecl_http`.

In your WAMP directory locate `pecl.exe` and open a command shell. Type: `pecl install pecl_http` and the function call should work.

Comment: I used the command line u said and I didnt have to install anything but I could not find the `pecl.exe` so I used the `php.exe` that did the trick :) so thnx :)

Comment: Hm. But your command wasn't really `php.exe install pecl_http`, was it?

Comment: nope `pecl install pecl_http` inside the black screen of `php.exe` had to restart the server though

Comment: What do you mean "inside the black screen of php.exe"? I'm trying to get PECL to work on a WAMP or a ZWAMP stack and can't get it to work.

Comment: @WernerCD he meant "using the windows command prompt from where the php.exe is located"

Comment: @Trufa its try the pecl.bat file

Answer (score 0):

i have found this source of pecl_http package, but dont know how to make it work on wamp as there is no .dll file in there.

http://pecl.php.net/package/pecl_http

Answer (score 0):

This question is old now, so if you want pecl with wamp 2.2, click on the wamp icon, hover over php->php extensions and make sure that php_http has a checkmark next to it. Doing this enabled pecl for me.

Comment: I'm using Wampserver 2.4 but there's no php_http extension available...

Answer (score 0):

I'm using WAMPServer (x64) with PHP5.6.25 & I want to install "Blesta", the requirements need "Pecl - Mailparse", So:

1. I download "PHP Mailparse v2.1.6 (PHP v5.6)(Thread Safe)(vc11)(x64)"
2. I extract the download file in "C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\ext"
   folder
3. I add "extension=php_mailparse.dll" to file
   "C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\phpForApache.ini" but at the end of
   "Dynamic Extensions"
4. Restart the WAMPServer
5. Install "Blesta"

Note for #3 Example:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll

extension=php_mailparse.dll
```